# How to make sure Microsoft teams reloads website in teams channel tab every time it is updated?

Tags: microsoft-teams

For monitoring purposes I created a website (with ip restriction) that I added to a tab in a Microsoft teams channgel. So far so good. However, every time I update the website, the updated one is not shown in the teams tab. It just sticks with the first version of the website. I guess this is due to caching.
Is there a way to disable caching in a teams tab? Or is there a way to make teams check if there is a newer version of the website before displaying it every time the channel tab is visited?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Luuk actually you helped me. I will try in that way. I was looking for a solution within Microsoft Teams like a refresh button, equivalent to normal browsers. Thanks!

Comment: @rdatasculptor - There doesn't seems to be any functionality available like refresh button within Microsoft Teams.

To view newer version of website in Tab you have to uninstall the app and reinstall it again.

You should raise an user voice here:https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472